# Whats is the real difference between this two examples of using Dynamic with Grid

Tags: dynamic, grid-layouts

the question is relatively simple I think. This is the first example of the code which works:

```
DynamicModule[{tabClicked, buttonClicked},     
 TabView[{
   "First" -> 
    Dynamic@Grid[{{ Button["xx", tabClicked = 2; buttonClicked = 1], 
        Button["xx", tabClicked = 2; buttonClicked = 2]}}],
   "Second" -> Dynamic[buttonClicked]
   }, Dynamic[tabClicked]
  ]
 ]
```

while this doesn't:

```
DynamicModule[{tabClicked, buttonClicked},
 buildButton[idx_] := 
  Button["xx", tabClicked = 2; buttonClicked = idx];
TabView[{
  "First" -> Dynamic@Grid[{{ buildButton[1], buildButton[2]}}],
 "Second" -> Dynamic[buttonClicked]
 }, Dynamic[tabClicked]
 ]
]
```

I know I can "fix" it by removing the Dynamic in front of Grid. The problem is that in the real example I need it as the grid context and even it's size are dynamic. I would like to understand why separating construction of button's into a function I get this strange behavior. Looking at the variable names using InputForm[] shows that the presence of Dynamic in front of Grid somehow forces Mathematica to assign temporary names to variables used in the buildButton.
Many Thanks, 
Lukasz

Comment: The second tab does not work on the first code either.

Comment: Welcome to SE Mathematica.  It would be useful if you would state exactly what you are hoping the program will do. Do you really want two buttons in the first tab and none in the second? Whats wrong with `TabView[{1, 2}]`?

Comment: Thank you, it is a very stylized example of a larger problem. Here effectively I would like to have behavior like in example two, where once you click a button the TabView shows the second tab and displays the value associated with the button which was clicked. In real case I would simply display some detailed information about the object which is displayed in a given row of the table on the first tab.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated solution**

Here is another way that works.  It is perhaps to be preferred to the other two from a programming style point of view.  In the OP, the function `buildButton` depends on external variables.  It would be better to pass these variables to the function.  In this case, since the variables are to be altered, the symbols need to be passed to the function unevaluated.  Given the context I would choose to wrap the variables in `Dynamic`, [in the manner of controls](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToControlObjects.html#510982863).  The definition of `buildButton` may appear inside or outside the `DynamicModule`.  It makes no difference, in fact.

```
buildButton[idx_, Dynamic[tab_], Dynamic[button_]] := Button["xx", tab = 2; button = idx];
DynamicModule[{tabClicked, buttonClicked}, 
  TabView[{
    "First" -> 
       Dynamic@Grid[{{buildButton[1, Dynamic[tabClicked], Dynamic[buttonClicked]], 
                      buildButton[2, Dynamic[tabClicked], Dynamic[buttonClicked]]}}], 
    "Second" -> Dynamic[buttonClicked]}, Dynamic[tabClicked]]
 ]
```

---

**Original solutions**

Two solutions:

Put `buildButton` in the `DynamicModule`:

```
DynamicModule[{tabClicked, buttonClicked, buildButton}, 
 buildButton[idx_] := Button["xx", tabClicked = 2; buttonClicked = idx];
 TabView[{"First" -> Dynamic@Grid[{{buildButton[1], buildButton[2]}}],
    "Second" -> Dynamic[buttonClicked]}, Dynamic[tabClicked]]]
```

Or change `DynamicModule` to `Module`

```
Module[{tabClicked, buttonClicked}, 
 buildButton[idx_] := Button["xx", tabClicked = 2; buttonClicked = idx];
 TabView[{"First" -> Dynamic@Grid[{{buildButton[1], buildButton[2]}}],
    "Second" -> Dynamic[buttonClicked]}, Dynamic[tabClicked]]]
```

It has to do with when the symbols get processed by the front end from something like `` $CellContext`buttonClicked$$ `` to `` FE`buttonClicked$$26 ``, I think.  If they don't get the same number after the `$$`, they are really different variables.

*Edit update:*
It seems in the OP's code the variables `tabClicked` and `buttonClicked` get assigned symbols like `tabClicked$44774` and `buttonClicked$44774`, while the variables in the `TabView` get assigned symbols like `` FE`tabClicked$$26 `` and `` FE`buttonClicked$$26 ``.  However, I have been unable to figure out why this happens.  A halfway guess is that the definition of `buildButton` happens in the kernel, and `tabClicked$44774` etc. look like `Module` symbols instead of `DynamicModule` symbols (e.g. `` FE`tabClicked$$26 ``).  This is what led me to suggest putting `buildButton` in the list of `DynamicModule` variables, by the way.

Comment: Thank you!! It works.